# Is there a way to not require a favicon?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, icons, favicon

Is there a way, to take out the HTML link and provide a favicon or alternatively, not let it be requested - perhaps using .htaccess?

```
<link rel=icon href=icon>
```

For instance, when a user opens a [.pdf] or otherwise, there is no icon - displaying 'nothing' or at least it is transparent. The purpose, is to minimise the number of HTTP requests. You see, I do not want to have [the HTML link] at all - so a data URI is not necessarily an option. In other words, I wish to remove this HTML tag - displaying nothing like a [.pdf] file, in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a tag specifying the url of a favicon, most browsers will just send a blind request to www.yourdomain.com/favicon.ico and hope for the best (thanks to **w3d** for pointing this out). This isn't something you can prevent them from doing.

Although, from what I know, favicons are cached in the clients browser, so they won't even be sending requests for it on every page-load.

Comment: This is not what I was asking; this option displays a 'broken' page icon in the space of the browser - I want it to be transparent: 'like a [.pdf] file'.

Comment: What do you mean by "like a [.pdf] file"? You said you wanted to minimize the amount of HTTP requests. Your question was how to "not require a favicon". The answer to that is to simply not supply a favicon and there won't be any. If your browser shows a "broken" icon, then that is because of the browser, that won't generate any HTTP request. If you're asking how to create a transparent favicon, that is a completely different question that doesn't really involve programming.

Comment: This is not correct. If you don't have the HTML `link` tag, most browsers will blindly send a request for `example.com/favicon.ico` anyway - there is no way you can prevent this request.